# Unicode replacement character

Tags: java, unicode

How to avoid unicode replacement character for extended ASCII chars when UTF-8 encoding fails?

Is there a way to preserve extended ASCII chars by avoiding the unicode encoding in Java?

Comment: There is no such thing as "extended ASCII". ASCII defines the character values 0-127.

Answer (score 4):

**Encoding** Unicode data in UTF-8 *can not fail*. *All* Unicode characters can be encoded in UTF-8, so there is no failure condition (except maybe lack of memory or similar things).

If you **decode** UTF-8, then it can fail when the input is not really UTF-8. In that case, trying to decode it with UTF-8 is the wrong approach and there's no way to "fix UTF-8" to do the right thing: you must choose the correct encoding.

Could you provide some sample input and code to demonstrate what *exactly* it is, you're having problems with?

Answer (score -1):

There is no reason at all to avoid unicode encoding. The actual problems come with the poor old encodings.

Convert all your files in UTF-8 and start your application with the system property file.encoding set to UTF-8.

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Provide some more information about your context if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: A better solution would be to *specify* the encoding to be used in your code instead of relying on system properties being set "correctly".

Comment: In our database, data contains characters like Ô or æ Our java application returns a XML string that contains these characters fine. But when the application is treated as web service and encoding fails in case of axis 1.4 soap client but does not fail in case of xfire soap client. In the case of Axis, such characters (Ô or æ) are shown as replacement char - \ufffd in the end result. Axis is using utf-8. Not sure why this is happening. Our application needs to use Axis soap client unfortunatley. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.